# How to initialize functions in a class

Tags: python, class, pytorch

I wanted to create a model in Pytorch using the below code. I implemented the below class but when I want to use it, it gives the below error.

AttributeError: cannot assign module before Module.**init**() call

```
 class PneumoniaModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = torchvision.models.resnet18()
        self.model.conv1 = torch.nn.conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size = (7,7), stride = (2,2), padding =(3,3),    bias=False)
        self.model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(in_features = 512, out_features = 1, bias = True)

        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr = 1e-4)
        self.loss_fn = torch.nn.BCEWithlogitsLoss(pos_weight = torch.tensor([3]))

        self.train_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy()
        self.val_acc = torchmetrics.Accuracy()

    def forward(self, data):
        pred = self.model(data)
        return pred
  
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x_ray, label = batch
        label = label.float()
        pred = self(x_ray)[:,0]
        loss = self.loss_fn(pred, label)

        self.log("Train_Loss", loss)
        self.log("Step Train ACC :", self.train_acc(torch.sigmoid(pred), label.int()))

        return loss

    def on_train_epoch_end(self):
        epoch_average = torch.stack(self.training_step_outputs).mean()
        self.log("training_epoch_average", epoch_average)
        self.training_step_outputs.clear()  # free memory

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x_ray, label = batch
        label = label.float()
        pred = self(x_ray)[:,0]
        loss = self.loss_fn(pred, label)

        self.log("Val Loss", loss)
        self.log("Step Val ACC :", self.val_acc(torch.sigmoid(pred), label.int()))

    def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
        epoch_average = torch.stack(self.validation_step_outputs).mean()
        self.log("validation_epoch_average", epoch_average)
        self.validation_step_outputs.clear()  # free memory


    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return [self.optimizerer]
```

How to solve the given error